# FOSUerBundle override template not working

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the login and register templates for `FOSUserBundle` but I can't get it working, I'm doing what documentation says, but nothing happens all I can see is the default templates :S

This is my `app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig`

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</div>
{% endif %}
<p>Login!</p>
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
</form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

And this is my `app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\layout.html.twig`

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
            {% for key, message in messages %}
                <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                    {{ message|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, was able to resolve it by manually deleting app/cache/*

Comment: @SamDufel Yep, that was the problem I had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844670/fosuerbundle-override-template-not-working?noredirect=1#comment31272134_20845777 :P see answer comments

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to record it here to get it a little more visible - the accepted answer doesn't *really* cover the actual issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are extending fosUserBundle in your userbundle file:

```
<?php

 namespace Radsphere\UserBundle;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

 class RadsphereUserBundle extends Bundle
 {
   public function getParent()
   {
     return 'FOSUserBundle';
   }
 }
```

In addition, make sure the twig template, which you are extending, exists in the same folder structure like in FosUserBundle:
For example I extended login.html.twig and its location is at

```
src/Radsphere/UserBundle/Resources/views/security/login.html.twig
```

Comment: Original file is under `/dificildecision/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig`

I've tried to override from `app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig` and also `src/Web/DificilBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig` but original template is showing everytime, I've tried modifying the original one, and it shows my changes but, **only** if I modify the original one... I don't know what is going on :S

Comment: put it in your own user bundle which extends the Fosuserbundle. and try to clear the cache from time to time, it always helps :)

Comment: Oh god, the problem was the cache stuff... First time using symfony2 that I need to clear cache to see changes on a twig file :S I don't want to clear cache every single time when on development environment... Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, it was my navigator which was bugged, now I can change things without clearing cache :D thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Just to bring some attention to an alternative for people that may end up here, as per Sam Dufel's comment, this was caused (for me) by the cache folder not fully clearing (itself an issue caused by vagrant sharing folders and permissions)

Manually deleting the app/cache folder fixes it.